# SubMenu panel covers bottom button of it

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, submenu

I have a SideMenu Panel control in a WinForm. There is two buttons: Button1 and Button2. When click in Button1 its display a SubMenu from it. But when SubMenu is hidden, a space between Button1 and Button2 remains.

I already have the code to hide and show the SubMenu:

```
 Public Sub hideSubMenu()
    If SubMenu.Visible = True Then
        SubMenu.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub showSubMenu(subMenu As Panel)
    If (subMenu.Visible = False) Then
        hideSubMenu()
        subMenu.Visible = True
    Else
        subMenu.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

So that's not a problem.

What I want is have the Button1 above of Button2 when SubMenu is hidden and Button2 under SubMenu when SubMenu is visible.

How can I do to achieve that?

[image: SubMenu VISIBLE]

[image: SubMenu HIDE]

Comment: Your code would need to change the location of the button2.

Comment: Set the `Dock` property of `Button1`, `Button2`, and `subMenu` to `Top`. This should automatically do the magic for you.

Comment: @LarsTech There is not any other option? I was trying to avoid that solution. What happens if you have multiple SubMenus?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, I was expecting something with `Dock` property but I didn't know how to use it. When I set `Dock` to `Top` then the controls go to the top of the SidePanel. How can I solve this?

Comment: That's exactly what docking does. When you dock the controls to the top, they get _stacked_ from top to bottom (isn't that what you want?) based on their ZOrder.

Comment: It looks like `hideSubMenu()` is not doing anythig. What @Ahmed Abdelhameed is suggesting is a classic. You need to `SendToBack()` the subMenu Panel, then `SendToBack()` the Button that activates it, while you `SuspendLayout()` - `.ResumeLayout(true)` the Control that contains these Buttons and Panels. You could also use an actual Menu. Another classic.

Comment: You didn't share enough information for us to give you better tips.  Try putting all these "menu panels" inside a UserControl.  Then you can put each panel with a Dock.Top as suggested.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I want the controls (Button1, Button2, SubMenu) inside SideMenu but not _stacked_ at top. If I set `Dock` property to `Top` in these controls then they will _stacked_ one on top of the other at the top of the SideMenu.

Comment: No, they don't. If you learn how to handle `Dock = Top` + `SendToBack()` and `BringtoFront()`.

Comment: @Jimi I did it with your solution that was suggested for Ahmed Abdelhameed in first place, thanks a lot both. I understood 
many things here. Now I'm trying to get the location of Button2 after click on it when the SubMenu is showed. The goal is to add the leftBorder (skyblue in the image) to the Button2 dinamically. There is any button event or way to do this?

Comment: I suppose (without knowing anything of your design) that you can use the `Enter` and `Leave` events to redefine the Buttons' aspect. In case these Buttons aren't already, they should be UserControls, or Custom Controls (so you apply all the layout logic in one place only).

Comment: @Jimi The event I was looking for is `MouseUp`. From there I can get the final location of `Button2`.

Comment: `    Private Sub Button2_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseUp
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            MsgBox("(" & Button2.Location.X & "," & Button2.Location.Y & ")")
        End If
    End Sub`

Comment: @Jimi After docking all controls in the SideMenu `Panel` I want to collapse that `Panel` whitout collapse the controls inside of it. There is any trick to do that?